# Get contacts from contact group based on group ID

Tags: android, contactscontract

I have a found a great [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334649/accessing-android-contact-group-names) on how to retrieve contact groups from the phone:

```
final String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] {ContactsContract.Groups._ID, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, GROUP_PROJECTION, null,  null, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE);
      while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

          String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID));
          String gTitle = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE)));

          if (gTitle.contains("Group:")) {
            gTitle = gTitle.substring(gTitle.indexOf("Group:") + 6).trim();
          }
          if (gTitle.contains("Favorite_")) {
               gTitle = "Favorites";
          }
          if (gTitle.contains("Starred in Android") || gTitle.contains("My Contacts")) {
              continue;
          }
          arr_groups.add(gTitle);
          arr_groupswithid.add(id + "." + gTitle);
}
```

The result is:

[image]

I have no idea why I get more of the same group with different id-s. Maybe as Abhishek suggested it has something to do with contacts stored on sim, phone or synced from Facebook or Gmail.

Ignoring this I have been trying to retrieve the contacts belonging to a specific group, but I never get the correct numbers.

```
String groupId = "10";
String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + "="
               + groupId + " AND "
               + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE + "='"
               + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
               ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
               new String[] {
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                       ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
               }, where, null, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

Log.i("cursorc", c.getCount() + "");
```

If the groupId==10, I get 7 contacts. If it is ==12, I get 11. If it is ==5, I get 0. All in all 18, which is good, as I have 18 persons in the Coworkers group, see image below.

If the groupId==3, I get 0 contacts. If it is ==9, I get 2. If it is ==13, I get 0. All in all 2, which is good.

If the groupId==1, I get 0 contacts. Where the hell are my Favorites?? It should give me 2.

If the groupId==6, I get 0 contacts. Where the hell are my Frequent Contacts?? It should give me 17.

These are my groups in my phone:

[image]

I don't know what to do now.

Comment: What is your question? And what do you expect from us for this question?

Comment: check if you have multiple contacts in the same group, maybe thats why you have multiple groups appearing

Answer (score 2):

your groups ACCOUNT_TYPE is different so you get same name with different id and different count so you should determine your type that you want to get group of it's type in your selection for example you can change your selection to

```
final String GROUP_SELECTION = ContactsContract.Groups.AUTO_ADD + " = 0 "
                + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = 'com.google' "
//              + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = 'DeviceOnly' "
//              + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = 'vnd.sec.contact.phone' "
                + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_WITH_PHONES + " > 0 "
                + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME + " NOT NULL  "
                + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.FAVORITES + " = 0 "
                + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED + " = 0  ";
```

this only show your groups that have com.google as there ACCOUNT_TYPE

Comment: what will be the selection argument for this selection query?

Comment: no need for that cause i put the values directly ; if you want you can add your question mark (?) on each field that you want @SagarHudge