# How to open contact showing the "Group" tab using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-contacts, contactgroups

I want to open Contact from my own Android app.

If I do :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

I can open contact, showing the *People* tab. How can I achieve a similar goal but showing the *Group* tab instead? Changing to `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_GROUP_URI` or `ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI` does not work. Once clicked, it would give a popup "Could not complete operation" and the following message in the console:

```
01-14 17:21:36.525: W/ContentResolver(26851): Failed to get type for:
  content://com.android.contacts/contacts/group/0 (
    URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/group/0,
    calling user: android.uid.system:1000,
    calling package is one of: [
      com.motorola.usbcamera,
      com.motorola.android.deepsleepservice,
      com.android.keychain,
      com.motorola.blur.setup,
      com.android.settings,
      com.motorola.atcmd,
      com.android.portal,
      com.android.vpndialogs,
      com.motorola.meter.omap,
      com.motorola.dockcomm,
      com.motorola.blur.setupsettings,
      com.android.providers.settings,
      com.motorola.Upgrader,
      com.motorola.devicestatistics,
      com.motorola.android.eapauthservice,
      com.motorola.android.fota,
      android,
      com.motorola.android.providers.settings,
      com.motorola.atcmdlauncher,
      com.google.android.backup,
      com.motorola.globalunplug,
      com.motorola.android.encryption.settings,
      com.motorola.blur.provider.datacollector,
      com.motorola.datacollection,
      com.motorola.dataswitch,
      com.android.systemui,
      com.motorola.contextual.fw,
      com.motorola.vpn,
      com.motorola.android.extdispservice,
      com.motorola.android.dlnasystemservice
    ]
  )
```

**EDIT**
Or is it possible to programmatically switch to "Group" tab after starting contact with "People" Tab ?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI ?

Comment: ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't tried yet, you should try this:

```
ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI
```

This is the URI for the groups table.

**EDIT:**

Here's the official link for reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Groups.html#CONTENT_URI

I'm sorry, but it does seem it's not possible.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734319/android-contactscontract-groups-activity-ui

[Accessing Android Contact Group Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334649/accessing-android-contact-group-names)

It looks like for now, Groups.CONTENT_URI is only for fetching group data, not opening the activity.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. But I have already tried this and it did not work.

Comment: @LeonQiao yes Leon, after some research and some codes tried it does seem it's not possible for now.

Comment: Thanks man. In that case, is it possible to programmatically switch to "Group" tab after opening contact showing "People" tab ?  @eestein

Comment: @LeonQiao Yesterday I tried some codes without success. I'll give a look today and see if that's possible. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: @LeonQiao Hi, I've tried some stuff, from looking for extras to trying to get the current running app and modify it, but with no success. I'm sorry, but I don't think it's possible, not even with a workaround. I guess you'd have to wait for Google to allow this through new Intent().

Comment: Yeah. I also tried but nothing worked out for me. But thank you for the help :D  @eestein

Comment: http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-programmatically-create-group-contact-with-image-photo-example/ I know its not exactly what you want but I am searching too